# Parse.com js api- Storing Password Data For Other Services

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to build a web app, which will among other things store users username & password for a third party service (a retailer) for use with their API.

I need to store these in a secure manner that is unreadable except by the web app when it uses the data for use in the JSON query to the retailers API.

My question is, where is the best place to store it?  Presumably the users class is the best as another class will not have the same security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same level of security to any collection you create in Parse. Namely you can either use plain-old [ACLs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-access-control-lists), [Class-Level-Permissions](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-class-level-permissions) (short CLP) or [Pointer Permissions](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-pointer-permissions) to limit/secure access to the objects stored in that collection.

In addition to the three different permission models you can use, consider adding Cloud Code to make the API requests to the 3rd party so you never have to send the credentials to the client.